# Google Analytics Real-Time API batching calls - order of returned data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I am trying to batch calls to GA Real-time api but I came across a strange issue. Let's say I want to get 10 dimensions. Since there is max dimension limit of 7 per call, I have to divide it to two calls (I am using Google App Script). For example:

```
const res = Analytics.Data.Realtime.get(
      "ga:xxxxxxx",
      "rt:activeUsers",
      {
        dimensions: [dimensions] // 7 dimensions here
      }
    )
```

and

```
const res = Analytics.Data.Realtime.get(
      "ga:xxxxxxx",
      "rt:activeUsers", // at least one metric is required so calling for active users again
      {
        dimensions: [dimensions] // 3 remaining dimensions here
      }
    )
```

It would seem like evertyhing is working fine but the order in which i receive data is either reversed or random. For the first call it would be something like this:

```
rows: 
    [ [ 'Chrome',
        '(not set)',
        'MOBILE',
        '(not set)',
        '(not provided)',
        '(not set)',
        'Redmi Note 7',
        '1' ],
      [ 'Firefox',
        '(not set)',
        'DESKTOP',
        '(not set)',
        '(not set)',
        '(not set)',
        '(not set)',
        '1' ] ],
```

For the second:

```
rows: [ [ '(not set)', '(direct)', 'NEW', '1' ],
      [ '(not set)', 'google', 'NEW', '1' ] ],
```

So the chunks of data are corresponding to each other like on this screen
[image]

I did a couple of tests and it seems like the order is reversed. But is it really? Maybe it's just random? I couldn't find any guidelines in docs so I don't want to rely on my experiments alone. Have you had any experience with that?

Comment: submit a bug report and i will ping the team with it.  TBH i never bother with batching there is really no benefit to it in my view. I suggest you run a few single tests then batch tests to show which way its going but that will probably be hard due to the nature of the real time api.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to make a connector for Google Data Studio and I don't really see other option. If there are 20 dimensions required in the report calling them one by one would  quickly exhaust the daily quota. Especially if there are many users and for example plugins for refreshing data are used.

Comment: After second thought it doesn't make sense what I just wrote because calling the dimensions one by one would not solve my problem :P. The nature of GDS is that you are able to call all available dimensions and metrics at once. So you basically have to return all data at once

Comment: Batching doesn't help with your quota each request counts as one against your batch i you have five in a batch its still five against your quota.   The only thing batching helps with is the http request throughput

Comment: yes exactly. I confused some separate issues. My basic problem is that you can have a report in GDS showing all available dimensions in one table and I have to figure out how to do that :)

Comment: Remember this is a multi dimension database not a relation database.    What you want to do isnt going to make any sense the analytics wont work.

Comment: Ok so maybe showing all dimensions at once doesn't make much sense :D. But still I could imagine that dimensions such as these would make sense in one table: `rt:campaign, rt:source, rt:trafficType, rt:medium, rt:country, rt:userType, rt:browser, rt:operatingSystem`. This is just one quick example because I believe there are much more combinations that require 7+ dimensions and still make sense. After all it all comes down to one metric which is "active user" and this user can have many dimensions.